# Why do I need to write "std::string" but not "std::getline()"?

Tags: c++, include, std

Consider this bit of code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                   
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string str;
  std::cout << "Enter a string: \n";
  getline(std::cin, str);
}
```

Why must I use `std::` for `string`, `cin` and `cout`, but not `getline()`?  Is `getline()` not in the standard library?  I'm actually somewhat confused why I can't just write `using namespace std;` and not have to `#include` anything in the standard library, too.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @norlesh: It is. But that's not the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Re the magic automatic namespace qualification.

It's Andrew Koenig's<sup>*</sup> fault.

He considered the problem of providing operators for user defined types. And came up with the idea of resolving the function depending on its arguments. E.g. with an argument of type defined in namespace `std`, the compiler looks (also) in namespace `std`.

That's called either [**Koenig lookup** or **ADL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), short for *Argument Dependent Lookup*.

---

## Re `using namespace std;`.

For short exploratory programs you not only can, but to save work you should, do this.

However, the standard library defines some identifiers such as `distance` that are *very* likely to collide with names you use.

Hence, for more serious code consider whether other means of avoiding verbosity, might be better. Many programmers even maintain that you **should not** use `using namespace std;` in serious code. Some Norwegian firms have this as a coding guideline (I don't agree with so absolute a view, but you should know that it's there, and may be a majority view).

At any rate:

**Never put a `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in a header**

because that makes name collisions like `distance` very likely for some code that includes the header.

---

## Why `using` doesn't make things accessible.

Many programming languages, such as Java and C# and Ada and Modula-2 and UCSD Pascal, just to name some, have language support for separately compiled modules, where a **module** consists of functions, variables, types, constants, maybe more.

Depending on the language a module may be called a "module" (Modula-2), a "package" (Ada, Java), a "unit" (Pascal), a "class" (Eiffel), so on.

C++ has a much more primitive system of separate compilation, where essentially the compiler proper knows *nothing* about modules. The preprocessor can drag in text from "headers", which provides a way to get *consistent declarations* of things. And to easily get those declarations.

But that's all, and the current primitive text inclusion system has a large number problems, most manifestly visible via various compilers' support for so called "precompiled headers" (not part of the C++ standard!).

David Vandevoorde has worked on a [**module proposal** for C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2316.pdf).

Sadly, it wasn't ready for C++11, but maybe it will come later.

<sub>*: In a comment [David Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36565/david-rodriguez-dribeas) adds that “it is not really Andrew's fault. He only intended ADL for operators, the committee extended that to all functions”.</sub>

Comment: +1, but it is not really Andrew's fault. He only intended ADL for operators, the committee extended that to all functions.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Question -- for something like `std::advance`, is it better to use `std::advance(i, d)` or to use `using std::advance; advance(i, d)`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: define "better" and there you have your answer. ;-) well personally i would not use qualification, for as i see it's just needless verbosity, and possibly in some cases establishing a counter-productive habit. consider writing qualified `std::swap(a, b)`, when a and b are of a user defined type. measuring someone finds that swapping via `std::swap` is too slow for this type, so a `friend` function `swap` is defined. but it will not be invoked by the qualified `std::swap`. which is where the habit got counter-productive (apart from verbosity/time considerations). just my view. ;-)